# How to define a dependency to download from azure artifacts in a gradle file?

Tags: gradle, azure-devops

I have setup an azure artifact feed, I can publish to it from an azure pipeline and I can connect to the feed from my local gradle file/project. However it is not clear how to actually define the dependency for building it locally as well as in the pipeline. I want to take it from this azure artifact place in azure devops so I can build my project anywhere and have the dependency. For example if I want to use a springboot dependency in my gradle file that downloads from mavencentral i use this in the dependencies section

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
```

How do I do this exact same thing but for my dependency that is located in the azure artifacts feed?

The relevant sections of my gradle file look like this

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<azure-username>/<myproject>_packaging/<my-feed>%40Release/maven/v1'
        name '<my-feed>@Release'
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15'
    implementation '<my-feed>:commons:0.0.1'
}
```

In addition I have added this settings.xml file to the ~/.m2 folder on my MBP.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id><my-feed>@Release</id>
      <username><my username></username>
      <password><my token provided by azure portal></password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

However when i try and build with gradle I get

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
>
> > Could not find :commons:0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Gradle build to look for dependencies in you Azure Artifact feed.

Assuming the feed is setup as a Maven repository, you can add the feed to the repositories section:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

```
repositories { 
    maven { 
        url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_packaging/{FeedName}/maven/v1' 
    } 
}
```

If the feed requires credentials, then you will need to configure that as well: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:handling_credentials

The URL format above is taken from the guide on how to publish to a feed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/publish-package-gradle?view=azure-devops

Comment: I've done that already and setup the settings.xml file with credential in the .m2 folder. I feel like it is connecting to the feed correctly because it was erorring out ebfore i added the credential. My question is how to define the dependency in the gradle file. The reason I am asking is if you go to maven central it will show you how to define a given dependency. it does not do this in azure which brings me to my above question

Comment: Right now I am getting an error from gradle when I try to build  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.

Comment: It can't find the azure dependency. I am assume it is connecting correctly though because I am not getting an auth error like i was getting before.

Comment: I have updated my question to include more contextual details of the problem.